# PHP preg_split("/[.,] \s /", $content) invalid argument passed

Tags: php, regex, preg-split

I am trying to split a variable that holds an articles content.

I want to loop through it to find keywords but I want to break up the content into an array.

```
preg_split("/[.,] \s /", $content);
```

So what I am doing here is splitting the content based on a "." or "," or a white space.

I was reading two different articles here on stack overflow one speaking about the split that is used like explode().

The other was about how the above syntex would work but I added the \s so I am assuming that is where I am going wrong. I have tried the \s within the bracket and out but still can't get it to work.

Comment: `preg_split("/[.,] \s /", "testing 12, 3")` works for me, so I'm guessing it's your `$content` that's the issue

Comment: If is a split for any of this options it should be `"/[ ,.]/"` (note the white space) only. Your expression is saying that it should have a dot or a comma and a space and any space/enter/tab and another space

Comment: Thanks for reply, its still not detecting the whitespace. Its breaking it down based on the ., but is now ignoring the whitespace.

Comment: That's odd. Try `/[\\s,.]/`

Comment: I think you are looking for this: `/[.,\s]\s*/`

Comment: Jorge Campos Excellent! that did it! I was thinking at the time you cant just put white space as whitespace could mean something different so I read \s means whitespace. Anyways all working thank you!

Comment: Glad that I could help :)

Comment: so one more time: you don't need to use a double slash.

Comment: Take care with the ´\s´ becaus it also means tabs and enter chars !

Comment: "/[ ,.]/" was the solution!

Comment: I will add it as an answer so your question maybe usefull to others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If is a split for any of this options that you have mentioned `space` or `.` or `,` the right pattern should be

```
preg_split("/[ .,]/", $content);
              |_ Note the whitespace here
```

Your expression is saying that it should have a `.` or `,` and a `space` and any `\s` (space/enter/tab) and another `space`